# Как разделить фрагменты массива - PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется следующее значение массива:

```
"time" => "12:00 - 15:00"
```

при выводе получается: `echo $massiv['time'] // 12:00 - 15:00`
необходимо вывести в текущем значении: `С 12:00 ДО 15:00 (С/ДО)`

можно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$explodedTime = explode('-', $massiv['time']);
echo "С {$explodedTime[0]} ДО {$explodedTime[1]}"; // echo "С {$explodedTime[0]}ДО{$explodedTime[1]}";
```

Comment: так и просится  в код `$explodedTime = array_map('trim', $explodedTime)`

Comment: Да. но в зависимости от нужд автора. Возможно ему достаточно второго варианта (который закомментирован)